# Interrogate lambda for captures?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, garbage-collection

Suppose I have an `Object` *o*, and an `Action` *a* that was constructed from a lambda. Is there any way I can use (e.g.) reflection or the GC to determine whether *a* captures *o*?

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd possibly *want* to do that.  What's your *actual* problem?

Comment: Note that the implementation details of how closure objects are structured is entirely subject to change (and has in fact changed over the years), so any such implementation could break at any time, for any version of the language, and so would be *extremely* unreliable and unsafe.

Comment: It's in the context of setting up a weak event subscription. You give the function an object and a lambda. The mechanism creates a weak reference to the object, and when the event fires, if the weak reference is still alive, gets its target and passes it to that lambda. But if the lambda captures a strong reference to the object, it defeats the whole purpose. Programmer error, but it would be nice to be able to detect this and alert the coder that s/he made a mistake.

Comment: @Servy If there is a way to ask the GC if o is reachable from a, that would presumably not break even if the compiler starts putting lambdas together differently.

Comment: Given your problem, the lambda shouldn't close over the variable, it should accept a value as input, and then your event manager should manage the weak reference and pass the appropriate value to the delegate.

Comment: No, the GC doesn't expose that operation, and trying to solve *that* would be *dramatically* harder than the problem you asked; you'd pretty much need to re-write the GC from scratch to do that.

Comment: @Servy That's exactly what it does, but sometimes programmers screw up and capture things they don't mean to. I would like to detect that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are OK with an approximate solution. In that case you can indeed use Reflection to traverse the object graph. All object references except those on the stack are visible through reflection. You need to look at all fields and all array elements.

Writing this is not that hard but it's quite unreliable and slow. If you are unlucky your traversal will find huge object graphs and spend a lot of time collecting them.

Maybe you can simplify the problem to say that only direct references from `a.Target` to `o` count. That would be easier. Simply look at all field values of `a.Target`.

There is no built-in API to do any of this, and thank god for that. This is the ultimate layering violation because no implementation detail remains hidden.

Comment: That does work. As you say, it's ugly and you need to put an upfront limit on the number of levels you're willing to recurse through, but for a sanity check that's only going to be enabled in debug builds, I think it will work fine.

Comment: I have done the same thing, btw. I have a little library to programmatically uncover memory leaks. I used it to debug why a global cache held onto local objects it was not supposed to hold onto.